# How pass a variable ( not uniform) float value from c++ to a vertex shader OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl-es

How can I send to pour shader values ​​from c + +, I know I can use the uniform type, but this did not valid because it is necessary to modify the value in each vertex and uniform is constant, I have seen that there is a kind "in" and "out" but do not support OpenGL ES 2.0, you send me an example of how to pass these values ​​to the vertex shader float, I send them part of the code that I'm using.

```
attribute float cppValue;
varying float valueV;

void main ()
{
valueV= cppValue;
}

exampleValueCpp float = 1;
glVertexAttribPointer (0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, & exampleValueCpp);
```

*UPDATE*

I have seen that there is a function "glVertexAttrib1f" and "glVertexAttrib1fv" to modify the attributes but I think it can only be used with glBegin and glEnd and these functions are obsolete in OpenGLES 2.0 or more, I'm right?, Is not going Asher possible to send a value not constant the vertex shader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want each float to be different for each vertex then you should have an array where they are collected:

```
float* exampleValueCpp = new float[numVertex];
for(int i = 0;i<numVertex;i++){
    //fill values
}
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);//use application memory
glVertexAttribPointer (0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, exampleValueCpp);
```

however you can also upload it into a VBO and use it like that:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &cppBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cppBuffer);

float* exampleValueCpp = new float[numVertex];
for(int i = 0;i<numVertex;i++){
    //fill values
}

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertex*sizeof(float), exampleValueCpp, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
delete[] exampleValueCpp;
glVertexAttribPointer (0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);//last parameter is offset into the buffer
```